# Восстановление GRUB после установки Windows

Tags: linux, windows, grub, dual-boot

Установлены две ОС Windows7 и Ubuntu. Переустановил Windows7, он конечно плевал на GRUB и установил свой загрузчик. Как мне восстановить загрузочную запись с моей Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Загрузиться с LiveCD Linux и выполнить команду типа

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Вместо `/dev/sda` необходимо подставить правильное имя устройства, если их в системе несколько.